# GNU Make: define a local variable that will never import?

Tags: makefile

Suppose I have a `gnu-make` automation node (this isn't an actual thing; it is something I use make for).

```
makefile
runFoo/
  runFoo.mk
thisBar/
  thisBar.mk
```

And inside the `makefile`, I have:

```
# makefile
include runFoo/runFoo.mk
include thisBar/thisBar.mk
```

Now, what I want to do is have a set of variable names that I always use. For example, `node` or `nodeName` would be a great variable that is defined for all of my "nodes" in the automation neighborhood that I've defined:

```
# runFoo/runFoo.mk
nodeName=runFoo
$(nodeName): 
   ~/.local/bin/runFoo.sh # for example

# thisBar/thisBar.mk
nodeName=thisBar
$(nodeName):
  @touch $@/$@
```

And the question amounts to:

**Is there some way** to define a variable such that it is used locally in the included file, but does not clash with any re-definitions in other files?

I.e., in the main makefile,

```
echo:
  @echo $(nodeName)
```

Would print nothing:

```
~$ make echo
```

---

I am looking at MAKELEVEL in the documentation, which is almost what I'm aiming for...

Basically, the idea is to define a `this` variable/name for a makefile a la C++ OOP.

Comment: I think the answer is no. What behaviour do you expect if you assign a variable in one of these Makefiles and use it in another? For instance, if a target-specific variable is defined in `foo.mk` but the rule for this target is elsewhere. But let's wait until MadScientist reads your question, he may have a better idea on how to emulate what you want.

Comment: There is no such thing as scoping on a file level, in makefiles.  Including in makefiles is like `#include` in C/C++ preprocessor: it doesn't introduce a new scope.  Using target-specific variables is a possibility, as is dynamic variable names.  See http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/  I've also done things like have a list of variable names that are always reset to empty after every `include` (you have to do this explicitly but you can put it into a macro).

Comment: @MadScientist I guess what I could do is `include blankNode.mk`, which would use the include process as the macro, and set up the list of defaults.

Comment: @MadScientist I think constructed macro names will take me an afternoon on the weekend :)